# The badge is over and hides the text

Tags: flutter

How can I make sure that the Badge does not go over the text?

```
Tab(
icon: Badge(
position: BadgePosition.topRight(),
badgeContent: Text("153"), 
child: Text("FHAZ"), ))
```

[[image: Pic 1]

[[image: Pic 2]

Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust Position as you want by providing custom value in topRight.

You can pass any value in negative which will take it to more right and upper side.

```
position: BadgePosition.topRight(top: -20, right: -30),
```